# How to protect dash/minus character when passing arguments to a configure script?

Tags: linux, configure

Under Linux, I'm trying to compile Qt in Debug mode and I want libraries to have "-g" infix.

So I try to configure using this command:

```
./configure -prefix ../compiled_debug_prefix -debug -qtlibinfix -g
```

But then I get and error:

```
ERROR: No value supplied to command line option 'qtlibinfix'.
```

There is no error if I set `-qtlibinfix g`, but then infix is "g" while I want "-g".

I suspect the fact that my parametere value starts with a minus sign messes up arguments parser. I tried `"-g"`, `\-g` with no success (still getting the same error). Is there any trick to have `-g` be interpreted correctly?

Comment: If this -g is part of the argument for -qtlibinfix you could try to single quote it and maybe even escape the - . -qtlibinfix '-g' or -qtlibinfix '\-g'

Comment: double quote will expand the value while single won't. I think this can make the difference. Not a pro though.

Comment: @TheFool: The quotes are removed before passing the argument from the shell to the executed program in both the cases.

Comment: The usual way is to put `--` as a parameter before `-g`, but I don't know whether Qt's configure supports it.

Comment: @TheFool: '-g' produces the same error. '\-g' makes configure work, but then generated files are using Qt5Core/g.so which leads to other compilation problems...

Comment: @choroba: Forgot to mention that I already tried `./configure -prefix ../compiled_debug_prefix -debug -qtlibinfix -- -g` with no success.

Comment: I too don't know Qt's configure, but I seem to recall GNU's configure options, like `prefix`, always started with 2 dashes: `--prefix`.

Comment: @Roadowl: What does that mean? What do you propose the correct command arguments should be?